# Map C++ Sort and Insert elements by value

Tags: c++, dictionary

How to create a custom comparator to insert and sort elements by value in a map in C++? Generally in a map, elements are sorted by key. I want to soet by value.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted result?

Comment: It is as contradictory as "dehydrated water". By definition, the thing being sorted by is the key or a part of the key. By definition, you can't sort by value.

Comment: if you sort by value, that value is the "key"

Comment: Keep in mind that keys are required to be unique, but values are not.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible in C++ to sort map based on its values due to its internal implementation.
Map sorts elements only based on its key.

But there is a way you can achieve what you want.(Both needs additional space though.)

1) If you only want all the values to be sorted & not needing their mapping. You can put all the keys in a vector and then sort the vector.

2) And suppose you want that mapping too. Then you can create a vector of pair<> and then define a comparator to sort based on second value of pair.

```
bool sortBySecond(const pair<int, int> &a, const pair<int, int> &b){
    return (a.second < b.second);
}
```

Inside main:

```
vector<pair<int, int> > vect;
sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(), sortBySecond);
```

The above vector will have pair sorted on the basis of your values of map in ascending order.